# Foursquare venues search api not working because old version

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5, foursquare

I am working on the FourSquare venue search API to get list of the venues. The following API link was giving results

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=40.7099,73.9622&v=20160607&intent=checkin&limit=5&radius=4000&client_id=WFFFI123B04PD44LMEPZAI25EUKC4FBRGI3NHQP15OQM0EIL&client_secret=ZYFJCGUVQ0KIZMSH0PCNNAZMK1JANQ2ZRRHJVGGHRYKC3FPK

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 410,
        "errorType": "deprecated",
        "errorDetail": "Usage of the V2 Places API has been deprecated for new Projects. Please see our updated documentation for V3 for more details: https://docs.foursquare.com/reference",
        "requestId": "619928ff498a047e3a81f23a"
    },
    "response": {}
}
```

Unfortunately the api documentation not working , and this like of the documentation

https://developer.foursquare.com/reference/v2-venues-search-request

Comment: So what is your question? Looks like the error is clear enough. They also clarify it here: https://developer.foursquare.com/reference/venues. It says to use Places API: https://developer.foursquare.com/reference/place-search

Comment: thank you very much I did not see the note